# SDK name of PluginsSDK not set?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, liferay, liferay-ide

I am using Liferay 6.2 + Tomcat 7.0 for creating a web application using portlets.

Now, When I want to work for some different project (creating a webservice), Whenever i create a Dynamic web project using Eclipse IDE, I get an error which says -

```
The SDK name of this PluginsSDK project is not set.
```

[image]

I tried downloading a fresh copy of Tomcat 7.0 and pointed it to the new project still getting the same error.

Can anyone please suggest what I might be missing here?

**EDIT**:

I do not get the project validation option in eclipse:

[image]

Comment: Since you are missing the Project Validation preference page you might not be using the latest Liferay IDE. Have you tried updating it?

Answer (score 3):

This is a bug in Liferay IDE plugin.

If your Project is not Liferay Plugin then it shows same error

This might help you [Click here](http://www.liferay.com/en_GB/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/35691415)

This issue has been resolved in latest version of Liferay IDE

Comment: rather than using the latest SDK, you should use the latest version of Liferay IDE. Well, using the latest SDK is not bad either, but doesn't help you with regards to your question

Comment: @ajc As i suggested you need install latest Liferay IDE.seems its realted to IDE not SDK as per the link which i shared.Please install latest IDE and give a try.

Answer (score 1):

Disable the validation: Window -> Preferences:

[image]

Comment: I do not get the option of project validation under Liferay.

Comment: Update your Liferay IDE to the latest version - there you'll find it